# Finding numbers from LCM and HCF

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Let two numbers be $x$, $y$ and their LCM and HCF be $L$ and $H$ respectively. Then,

$7H=L$ and
  $x+y=392$
How can I find $x$ and $y$? I have tried to use $7 (\gcd)^2=xy$ but nothing came out of it. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: You have not used $x+y = 392$ as yet.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = a H, y = b H$, where $\gcd(a,b) = 1 $. Then $L = abH$, so $ab=7$. Thus, we must have $\{a, b \} = \{1, 7\}$. WLOG, $x=H, y = 7H$.

Comment: Thank you!I did not realize that this problem was this simple.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$\gcd(x,y)=h \implies x=kh, y=mh$ and LCM=$kmh$, $7\gcd=LCM \implies km=7$